# excel header formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using following subprocedure to fill some cells starting with cell AS9 
but somehow the subprocedure modifies also the header from AS8. I don't want to modify the header when I run the subprocedure

```
Sub actualizareformule()

    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("AS9:AS" & Lastrow).Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1],""0%"")"   

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use explicit parent sheet references throughout and possibly add a check that Lastrow is >= 9.

Answer (score 1):

You should add one to last row. This way you will add your formula starting from next row (one below). Try this:

```
Sub actualizareformule()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find last row and add one
Lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("AS9:AS" & Lastrow -1).Formula = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1],""0%"")"

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: it's working with the header but now the formula is completed with one extra row

Comment: Edited - check now (I have corrected LastRow value)